# How to just pass in primary key values to my CRUD functions?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, crud, razor-pages

Here is my code:

**albums.cshtml**

```
@page
@model Project.Pages.AlbumsModel            
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

<div class="row">
    <h1 class="display-2">Albums</h1>
    <table class="table">
        <thead class="thead-inverse">
            <tr>
                <th>Album ID, artist ID, Album title</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (string album in Model.Albums)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@album</td>
                    <td><a asp-page="/Albums/Delete" asp-route-id="@album">Delete</a></td>
                    <td><a asp-page="/Albums/Edit" asp-route-id="@album">Edit title</a></td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <p>Enter a title & ArtistID for a new album:&nbsp;</p>
    <form method="POST">
        <div><input asp-for="Album.Title" /></div>
        <div><input asp-for="Album.ArtistId" /></div>
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
</div>
```

**albums.cshtml.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Project.Models;
using System;

namespace Project.Pages
{
    public class AlbumsModel : PageModel
    {
        private Chinook db;

        public AlbumsModel(Chinook injectedContext)
        {
            db = injectedContext;
        }
        public IEnumerable<string> Albums { get; set; }
        public void OnGet()
        {
            ViewData["Title"] = "Chinook Web Site - Albums";
            Albums = db.Albums.Select(s => s.AlbumId.ToString() + ". " + s.ArtistId + ". " + s.Title);
        }
        [BindProperty]
        public Album Album { get; set; }

        public IActionResult OnPost()
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Albums.Add(Album);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToPage("/albums");
            }
            return Page();
        }

        public IActionResult DeleteAlbum(int AlbumId)
        {
            var album = db.Albums.Find(AlbumId);

            if (album == null) return Page();

            db.Albums.Remove(album); db.SaveChanges(); return RedirectToPage("/albums");
        }
    }
}
```

**delete.cshtml**

```
@page  "{id?}"
@model Project.Pages.Albums.DeleteModel
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Delete";
}

<h1>Delete</h1>

<p class="text-danger">@Model.ErrorMessage</p>

<h3>Are you sure you want to delete this?</h3>
<div>
    <h4>Album</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="row">
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Album.Title)
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Album.Title)
        </dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Album.ArtistId)
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Album.ArtistId)
        </dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Album.AlbumId)
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Album.AlbumId)
        </dd>
    </dl>

        <form method="post">
        <input type="submit" value="Delete" asp-route-id="@Model.Album.AlbumId" class="btn btn-danger" /> |
        <a asp-page="/Albums">Back to List</a>
    </form>
</div>
```

**delete.cshtml.cs**

```
#region snippet_All
using Project.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Project.Pages.Albums
{
    public class DeleteModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly Chinook _context;

        public DeleteModel(Chinook context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public Album Album { get; set; }
        public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(string? id, bool? saveChangesError = false) //changed int -> string
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            //using string.split method to split the id parameter, and get the albumid.
            var albumid = System.Convert.ToInt32(id.ToString().Split('.')[0]);

            Album = await _context.Albums
                .AsNoTracking()
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.AlbumId == albumid);

            if (Album == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            if (saveChangesError.GetValueOrDefault())
            {
                ErrorMessage = "Delete failed. Try again";
            }

            return Page();
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var album = await _context.Albums.FindAsync(id);

            if (album == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            try
            {
                _context.Albums.Remove(album);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToPage("/Albums");
            }
            catch (DbUpdateException /* ex */)
            {
                //Log the error (uncomment ex variable name and write a log.)
                return RedirectToAction("/Albums/Delete",
                                     new { id, saveChangesError = true });
            }
        }
    }
}
#endregion
```

**edit.cshtml**

```
@page
@model Project.Pages.Albums.EditModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Edit";
}

<h1>Edit</h1>

<h4>Album</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="Album.AlbumId" />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Album.Title" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Album.Title" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Album.Title" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-page="/Albums">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

**edit.cshtml.cs**

```
using Project.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Project.Pages.Albums
{
    public class EditModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly Chinook _context;

        public EditModel(Chinook context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public Album Album { get; set; }
        public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

        #region snippet_OnGetPost
        // public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int? id)
        // {
        //     if (id == null)
        //     {
        //         return NotFound();
        //     }

        //     Album = await _context.Albums.FindAsync(id);

        //     if (Album == null)
        //     {
        //         return NotFound();
        //     }
        //     return Page();
        // }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(string? id, bool? saveChangesError = false) //changed int -> string
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            //using string.split method to split the id parameter, and get the albumid.
            var albumid = System.Convert.ToInt32(id.ToString().Split('.')[0]);

            Album = await _context.Albums
                .AsNoTracking()
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.AlbumId == albumid);

            if (Album == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            if (saveChangesError.GetValueOrDefault())
            {
                ErrorMessage = "Delete failed. Try again";
            }

            return Page();
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(int id)
        {
            var albumToUpdate = await _context.Albums.FindAsync(id);

            if (albumToUpdate == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            if (await TryUpdateModelAsync<Album>(
                albumToUpdate,
                "album",
                s => s.Title))
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToPage("/Albums");
            }

            return Page();
        }
        #endregion

        private bool AlbumExists(int id)
        {
            return _context.Albums.Any(e => e.AlbumId == id);
        }
    }
}
```

My code build and runs OK, but when I go to edit, I get, for instance

> This localhost page can’t be found
> No web page was found for the web address: https://localhost:5001/Albums/Edit/353.%20123.%20Test

I'm sure it should just be passing in the `AlbumId`, as in

> https://localhost:5001/Albums/Edit/353

...and when I manually change the URL to that, it works.

The delete function works from, for instance...

> https://localhost:5001/Albums/Delete/353.%20123.%20Test2

...where '353' is the `AlbumId`, '123' is the `ArtistId`, and 'Test2' is the `Title`.

...but that actually *does* work. So how can I just get both Delete and Edit to work from the `AlbumId`? That is all that's needed, right? TIA for any help.

Comment: Normally parameters are in the URL after a question mark and separated by ampersand.  See Wiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string?force_isolation=true

Comment: _asp-route-id="@album">_ should be _asp-route-id="@album.AlbumID">_ and, of course, you should change back the OnGetAsync in the Edit.cshtml.cs to receiving an integer

Comment: @jdweng - no, it's not like that, the URLs for both `Delete` and `Edit` are just like https://localhost:5001/Albums/Edit/353.%20123.%20Test

Comment: @Steve - I tried that, but I get "Pages\albums.cshtml(18,75): error CS1061: 'string' does not contain a definition for 'AlbumID' and no accessible extension method 'AlbumID' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found" Edit: I'm just trying to work on the `OnGetAsync` suggestion right now, thanks.

Comment: Why do you build an IEnumerable of strings from your Select? This is the root of your problems. Return an IEnumerable of Album and build a column for each element you want to display, then you can use @album.AlbumID

Comment: OK, that makes sense to me. I'll try to work on that now, thanks.

Comment: Webpages are html files (or applications/services that automatically open the html).  So you connect to a server (or IP address) and the location where the file is located (the route).  And the URL can have parameters.  You have a route, but your question asked how to add parameters.  In some cases the route could be parameters.

Comment: @jdweng - OK, thanks. I've tried to follow the suggestions Steve made, but I'm getting "Pages\albums.cshtml(33,15): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Album' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion your problem lies in the way you return the information from the Album.cshtml.cs. Instead of build an IEnumerable of strings return the IEnumerable of Album

```
public IEnumerable<Album> Albums { get; set; }
public void OnGetAsync()
{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Chinook Web Site - Albums";
    Albums = db.Albums;
}
```

Now, in the Album.cshtml file you can use the strongly typed Model to create the list of each album with links to delete and edit each row with the proper ID

```
<thead class="thead-inverse">
    <tr>
        <th>Album ID</th>
        <th>artist ID</th>
        <th>Album title</th>
        <th></th><th></th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
    @foreach (Album album in Model.Albums)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@album.AlbumID</td>
            <td>@album.ArtistID</td>
            <td>@album.Title</td>
            <td><a asp-page="/Albums/Delete" asp-route-id="@album.AlbumID">Delete</a></td>
            <td><a asp-page="/Albums/Edit" asp-route-id="@album.AlbumID">Edit title</a></td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

Finally you can change back the Edit and Delete code to receive the integer passaed in tha asp-route-id

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int id, bool? saveChangesError = false)     
{
    Album = await _context.Albums
        .AsNoTracking()
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.AlbumId == id);
    if(Album == null)
    .....
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to implement this, but I'm getting 
> Pages\albums.cshtml.cs(27,22): error CS4033: The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'.
> Pages\albums.cshtml.cs(27,22): error CS1061: 'DbSet<Album>' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no accessible extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'DbSet<Album>' could be found

Comment: I've fixed the above errors now, as I had forgotten to remove `await` from `Albums = db.Albums;`, but now I have "Pages\albums.cshtml(33,15): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Album' could not be found"

Comment: You should have an Album class defined somewhere in your code. You need to add its namespace to the using list at the top of your file. Or you can try the fast fix option in Visual Studio. Just move the cursor over the red underlined Album word and press Ctrl + . then accept the add using advice

Comment: Yes, I have an Albums.cs file, though it is in my Entities folder. It has `namespace Project.Models`, and then albums.cshtml.cs has `using Project.Models;`, so that seems to be what are you suggesting. I'm using Visual Studio Code, by the way (it's a course requirement). Thanks.

Comment: I was told that albums.cshtml also needs `@using Project.Models`. I thought that was just for the albums.cshtml.cs. So it's working now. many thanks.